# iOS Facebook SDK: show progress of received data with FBURLConnection

Tags: ios, facebook, frameworks, progress-bar

I'm using the Facebook-SDK to make some FQL queries. Now I want to know how much of the requested data has already been transferred to the app to visualize the loading process in a progressbar.

So I used this https://github.com/nyankichi820/FBRequestConnection-FBRequestConnection_progress plugin which extends the FBURLConnection class to provide the progress of a data transfer.

The problem is, that I included the Facebook-SDK as an XCode framework into the project and the header file FBURLConnection.h which is necessary for the plugin is not published in the framework and cannot be found.

So how can I include the header file FBURLConnection.h into the frameworks visible headers so that I can access it? I dont't want to include all the FB-SDK files, I wanted to do this by relying on the XCode framework structure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably include the source of the framework yourself manually or much more simply using cocoapods.

Here is the github link to the SDK source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

The official cocoapod is named "Facebook-iOS-SDK", if you decide to go that route. I recommend doing this as it is much simpler to install the SDK and update it later on. Cocoapods are very nice for external components in general and will almost certainly save you time and frustration in the long run.